.NET runtime needed - but it's actually installed
I have an .exe that was just migrated from .NET-Framework 4.8.1 to .NET 8.0.
My .csproj contains <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>.
If I want to run it, I get this error dialog:

Neat, loader will auto attempt to install required net-runtime dependency if missing.
Except that... I already have everything in place
dotnet --list-runtimes

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Following that link and installing it changes nothing, obviously. Same error.
Note that: required = v8.0.0 and I already have v8.0.8 (should work though).
What am I missing? Why am I getting that? And how to get rid of it?
Thanks
update: also tried installing 8.0.0, just in case.
Same result. App does not find any of my installed runtimes it seems.

Do you have a runtime targetframework configuration in your project that is set to 8.0.0?  or any other environment or runtime configurations being specific to 8.0.0 instead of just 8.0?
If any are specifically set to 8.0.0 than 8.0.8 is not going to work. You would need to specify 8.0 instead.

my csproj contains <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework> (updated question to include this detail). Thanks

there's no other configuration in my csproj related to the target framework/version.

8.0-windows should use later versions. Does it make a difference if you explicitly specify to use patch versions post 8.0 by adding  <RollForward>LatestPatch</RollForward> below <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework> ? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json#rollforward

Tried , same result :(. Thanks

Also tried installing 8.0.0, just in case. Same issue still.

The x86 and x64 are separate installers. Are you sure you have x64?

I have all these installed in 64 bit: core runtime + desktop runtime + asp.net runtime
confirmed by both dotnet --list-runtimes and also dotnet --info

tired with all this, got this as a workaround:
BootstrapperEnabled=true, SelfContained=true, RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64.
My executable starts. Why it fails to see existing runtimes? Still a mistery.
